# How do I rotate an isometric camera around the screen center?

Tags: python, c, rotation, sdl, isometric

I have a tile-based project game, got a nice pseudo-3d effect using multiple tile layers, but I would like to be able to rotate the camera (essentially, rotating the sprites).

But, simply rotating the sprites isn't equal to rotating the world, right?

By that, I got to:

```
x = (x - y) * (tile_width/2);
y = (x + y) * (tile_width/2);
```

But, see? That only works for 45 degree rotated tiles! How can I modify the angle used in those formulas (or maybe a better, more appropriate one)?

[image: Plain]
[image: Isometric]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rotating the sprites is only part of rotating the world/camera.

To rotate the world/camera, each tile needs to be moved along an arc, and rotated at the same time. To do that you need to use polar coordinates. Compute the distance and angle from the center-of-rotation to the center of each tile. Then add the desired angle-of-rotation to the polar angle for each tile. Compute the new `x` and `y` values for the center of the tile by converting back to cartesian coordinates.

Here's what the code might look like, assuming that each tile is represented by a struct, and that struct has the original `x` and `y` coordinates of the center of the tile (i.e. the coordinates of the center of the tile when the world is not rotated).

```
    // compute the distance from the center of the tile to the center of rotation
    double dx = tile[t].x - centerOfRotation.x;
    double dy = tile[t].y - centerOfRotation.y;

    // compute the new location of tile in polar coordinates relative to the center of rotation
    double r = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    double angle = atan2(dy, dx) + angleOfRotation;

    // compute the display location for the tile
    x = centerOfRotation.x + r * cos(angle);
    y = centerOfRotation.y + r * sin(angle);

    // note that the tile itself needs to rotated as well, using angleOfRotation
    // also, all angles are in radians
```

When attempting to rotate graphics, it helps to keep things simple. Use a small number of tiles, make the tiles different colors with strong borders, and an identifying mark to show orientation. Here's an example with 9 tiles in the initial orientation and rotated 30 degrees counter-clockwise.

[image] [image]

Here are some examples of what can go wrong:
1) moving the tiles without rotating the tiles
[image]
2) rotating the tiles without moving the tiles
[image]
3) rotating the tiles clockwise while moving the tiles counter-clockwise
[image]
Bottom line: Pretty much any mistake will result in an image with gaps.

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? What could be the cause of those gaps?

Comment: @WilliamFernandes The gaps are due to the fact that the tiles have not been rotated properly. The other indication is that the edges of the map are not straight. Note that there are two angles in the answer, the `angleOfRotation` and the computed polar `angle`. Each tile needs to be rotated by the `angleOfRotation`.

Comment: Note that in your 45 degree example, the tiles are not rotated at all. You can tell because the edges of the map are not straight, and also the dots in the grass are still squares, not diamonds. So an easy test is to rotate the tiles by 45 degrees in your example, to make sure that rotating tiles works properly.

Comment: The dots in the grass are still square because those are 8x8 sprites scaled four times (the game's resolution is 160x120 scaled up to 640x480). I'm rotating using `al_draw_rotated_bitmap(tileset[world[y][x]], 4, 4, pos_x, pos_y, r_angle, 0);`, and `r_angle = angleOfRotation`. What else could be wrong?

Comment: @WilliamFernandes Wild guess: try `-r_angle` in that call.

Comment: Did it, I guess it just rotates to the inverse direction, still with those gaps...